# How can I arrange my bibliography alphabetically?

Tags: bibliographies

I have generated the bibfile in latex for citation. But now I want to rearrange it alphabetically. Is there any coding for this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you use `biblatex`, there is a  `sorting=…` key, to be used at loading time.

Comment: Do you mean you want the bib file/bib database itself sorted, or the bibliography that appears in your document? If the former, look at [bibtool](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool?lang=en). If the latter, we need to know whether you're using bibtex or biber/biblatex, what style file you're using, what packages (e.g., natbib) or other relevant settings you're using.